# Grammar problem passive

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Can we use the word soon before past participle in passive sentences?
Is the following sentence correct?
The window will be soon installed.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just stick to the conventional "The window will soon be installed".

Comment: This question is ***soon answered***. Except I'm not going to.